# how to use youtube video in html video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I have youtube videos for my website and I want to show these videos in video tag of HTML5.
Is it possible to have iframe tag of **youtube** be embedded in video tag?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <video class="video_link" width="320" height="240" controls="controls" id="3"> 
      <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the embed frame youtube is giving to you? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score -1):

If a browser doesn't recognize the HTML5 video tag, then one can upload a Flash swf file and point to it in the src attribute in the embed tag, which is embedded in the video tag itself.

```
<video width="{#}" height="{#}" controls>
  <source src="{ogg_file}.ogg" type="video/ogg" />  
  <source src="{mp4_file}.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  

  <!-- The fallback in case the browser doesn't recognize the HTML5 video tag -->  
  <embed src="{flash_swf_file}.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="{#}" height="{#}"></embed>  
</video>
```

The iframe tag loads a page within an existing page. Maybe they wanted to have the video on a separate page specified by the iframe tag. Anytime you use an iframe, consider using this code in your CSS file because otherwise some browsers will show the box lines where the iframe is.

```
iframe[seamless] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px none transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

For the CSS code to work, seamless has to be included at the end of the opening iframe tag.

```
<div><iframe src="{page_name}.html" height="{#}" width="{#}" seamless></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to that video and click on share button you will embedded link for video.
just copy and paste where you want.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QBpz2fu10eY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```